# Need a Suggestion for a Good Class to use for Form display and validation (PHP)

Tags: php, class, forms

Thanks in advance, I am looking for a good way to make forms in php.  I don't want to have to create all the items in html and want it to look good, be easily validated, and in general be easy to work with.  Suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion: http://pof.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google turns up [Phorm](http://www.artfulcode.net/articles/phorms-a-php-form-library/) - unfortunately named as Phorm is also an ISP ad-targeting system over here in the UK.

It seems to do what you want - and I imagine you can style the result quite easily using CSS. It also isn't part of a larger framework, which is very hard to integrate into an existing project.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want.  Seems simple and to the point which is what I need for this project.

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/php-form-builder-class/

Answer (score 1):

[Symfony Forms Framework](http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/).

Comment: +1. It can automatically validate and render forms, and you only have to specify the schema. It's also very well-designed, easy to use and can be used standalone without the whole Symfony framework.

Comment: @Ignas R: Could you elaborate more on using symfony forms standalone, or maybe point me to some documentation about it?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.qcodo.com/ is a framework that has the form handling classes built-in. Pretty handy.

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted a component to YUI for form validation.  Its easy to use, and does most of the work for you.  Check it out

http://github.com/murdog05/yui2/downloads

Unfortunately Github is a bit slow today for reasons unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using (for many years now) [HTML_QuickForms](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform.php) combined with the [Tableless Renderer](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.html-quickform-renderer-tableless.php) for easily css styled forms with built in validation that is easy to extend. If you have access to pear classes it is extremely easy to integrate into your projects.